# Fourier transforms and the angular frequency

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, control-theory, signal-processing

In the context of Fourier transforms, is the following true?

> $$ \mathcal{F} \left( F(t) \right) =2\pi \, f(-\omega )  $$

If it is not, what small changes can I make to the equation to make it true?
I found the problem like that, but I think both uppercase $F$'s are supposed to denote a Fourier transform. The closest thing I have found so far is 
[this section in
Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions).
There, I found this:
$$ f(x)={\frac {1}{(2\pi )^{n}}}\int _{\mathbb {R} ^{n}}{\hat {f}}(\omega
)e^{i\omega \cdot x}\,d\omega $$

However, I am not sure what restrictions I need to make to use that last 
equation, or whether it is useful at all. I do not even think I completely understand it.

So, how can I make the equation at the top true?

Comment: First you should be aware of the fact that there are around 3-4 popular "Fourier transform" in the literature. The main distinction is where each author put $2\pi$ in their definition of Fourier transform. For this reason you might see similar formulas but with different constant term here and there.

Comment: @BigbearZzz , thanks for the comment. Do you know of any link (website) or book where I can find those 4 different Fourier transforms? If there is an explanation of the differences between all of them, that would be nice too.

Comment: The wikipedia page for Fourier transform also have such a list of other common definitions of FT. You can find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions

Comment: @BigbearZzz , you are right. I somehow missed that, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking:

Let $f$ be a nice function (say a Schwartz function). If we define the Fourier transform as $$\mathcal{F} f(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\, dx,$$ then we have the Fourier inversion formula: $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} R\mathcal{F},$$ where $R$ is an operator defined by $Rf(x)=f(-x).$ In particular, we get the formula you wrote in your post: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathcal{F}f(\xi)e^{ix\cdot\xi}\, d\xi.$$

For the formula you look like you want, you can get something like $$(2\pi)^n\mathcal{F}^{-1} f(x)=\mathcal{F}f(-x).$$

As for when this inversion holds, you can get pretty sharp results, depending on the generality you want to work in.

Comment: Thank you! What is the meaning of $R \mathcal{F}$ ? Later you use $R$ in $Rf(x) $. Is $R$ a constant?

Comment: Here, $R$ is an operator so that $Rf(x)=f(-x).$ So, $((R\circ \mathcal{F}) f(x) =) \ R\mathcal{F}f(x)=\mathcal{F}f (-x).$ In essence, you take the Fourier transform, then you change the variable from $x$ to $-x.$

Comment: Thanks. Regarding my original post, WLOG, I can replace $t$ by $x$. So, I would have $x$ on the left hand side, and $- \omega $ in the RHS (and I assume $\omega =2\pi x$ ? Or $2\pi \xi$ ? I am confused, but I'll review this later.). However, in your final equation I have $x$ on the LHS and $-x$ on the RHS. Is it possible to get $\omega $ somewhere?

Comment: In the same way, you can get that $(2\pi)^n\mathcal{F} ^{-1}f(-\omega)=\mathcal{F}f(\omega).$ I'm not sure exactly what $F$ and $f$ are in your original post. EDIT: Okay, if I'm understanding your post correctly, then what you wrote should be correct).

Comment: Thank you again. In this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions , the equation corresponding to "nonunitary angular frequency" is very similar to what you wrote. Is that the same to what is written in your answer? I have only used Fourier transforms with one variable, so I am confused by the $\mathbb{R}^n $ symbol.

Comment: Yup, that's the convention that I was working with. As for working in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ you can just take $n=1$ in all of my stuff (I chose it because of the inversion formula you wrote).

Comment: Got it. In your comment above you say that what I wrote should be correct. After reading your answer, I just thought that my very first equation (the one in yellow, as a blockquote) was wrong, and that I needed to, at the very least, have $\omega$ both on the LHS and on the RHS (because in your final equation you have $x$ both in the LHS and RHS). Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure, you effectively just take the Fourier transform of both sides. You can get that $2\pi f(x)=\mathcal{F}\left(\mathcal{F} f(\xi)\right)(-x).$ It actually just comes right out from using the Fourier inversion formula and writing everything out (by Fourier inversion, I'm specifically referring to the second-to-last formula in my original post).